# Mimicking the Python "for-else" construct

Tags: bash, for-else

Python has a handy language feature called "for-else" (similarly, "while-else"), which looks like this:

```
for obj in my_list:
    if obj == target:
        break
else: # note: this else is attached to the for, not the if
    print "nothing matched", target, "in the list"
```

Essentially, the `else` is skipped if the loop breaks, but runs if the loop exited via a condition failure (for `while`) or the end of iteration (for `for`).

Is there a way to do this in `bash`? The closest I can think of is to use a flag variable:

```
flag=false
for i in x y z; do
    if [ condition $i ]; then
        flag=true
        break
    fi
done
if ! $flag; then
    echo "nothing in the list fulfilled the condition"
fi
```

which is rather more verbose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using a subshell:

```
( for i in x y z; do
    [ condition $i ] && echo "Condition $i true" && exit;
done ) && echo "Found a match" || echo "Didn't find a match"
```

Comment: Short and sweet. I like it.

Comment: Big BUG! The list of `x y z` never gets to `y z` if `x` is false! @nneonneo how could you accept that?!

Comment: Here's what I'm using: `( for i in x y z ; do [ condition $i ] && echo "Condition $i true" && exit; done ) && echo "Found a match" || echo "Didn't find a match"`. Note the use of `&& exit` instead of `|| exit`, which is key to make it continue when `x` is false.

Comment: Hope you don't mind if I fixed the code to match what I asked for.

Answer (score 10):

You could put a sentinel value in the loop list:

```
for i in x y z 'end-of-loop'; do
    if [ condition $i ]; then
        # loop code goes here
        break
    fi
    if [ $i == 'end-of-loop' ]; then
        # your else code goes here
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 9):

Something very hacky to introduce similar syntax:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s expand_aliases

alias for='_broken=0; for'
alias break='{ _broken=1; break; }'
alias forelse='done; while ((_broken==0)); do _broken=1;'

for x in a b c; do
        [ "$x" = "$1" ] && break
forelse
        echo "nothing matched"
done
```

```
$ ./t.sh a
$ ./t.sh d
nothing matched
```

Comment: Cool. Aliases can be helpful sometimes.

Comment: @konsolebox I agree, aliases are way underrated. Even though they are themselves limited they help work around other limitations where they are the only (or prettiest) solution. I used this technique before to implement shell exception handling and while I am sure many people find this ugly and idiotic I think it's rather beautiful in a way.

Comment: It is actually an interesting use of aliases. Thank you for the solution (+1).

Comment: +1. Very interesting. (Reminds one of macros in C to mimic Pascal style.)

Comment: You probably don't need '==0' in the forelse alias, though.

Comment: @devnull True, you could e.g. use an `until` loop instead and skip the `==0` or just invert the toggle variable :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this but I personally find it hard to read:

```
while :;
  do for i in x y z; do
    if [[ condition ]]; then
      # do something
      break 2
  done
  echo Nothing matched the condition
  break
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I also enjoy devnull's answer, but this is even more pythonic:

```
for i in x y z; do
  [ condition $i ] && break #and do stuff prior to break maybe?
done || echo "nothing matched"
```

This will only echo "nothing matched" if the loop did not break.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this

```
if ! $flag; then
    echo "nothing in the list fulfilled the condition"
fi
```

to something simpler like this

```
"$flag" || echo "nothing in the list fulfilled the condition"
```

if you only have one statement after it, although that's not really going to help much.